# CSS line-height renders differently between IOS safari and Windows Firefox

Tags: html, css

When the line-heigh is less than the font-size, it renders differently between IOS safari and Windows Firefox

[image: Left is IOS safari, right is Firefow Windows]

Left is IOS Safari, right is Firefox Windows

Is there a way to prevent that ?

Comment: What the Font used is? His size? Line-heigt value?

Comment: Font-size : 200px with line-height : 130px, font used is Overpass but problem is the same with sans-serif